# Javascript -> how to recursively add an array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this code -> keeps throwing a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

```
function arrayIntSum(array) {
    if (array === []){
        return 0;
    }
    else return array.shift() + arrayIntSum(array); 
}
```

Comment: Did you event tried debugging, change your if condition before ask here? -1 for lazyness

Comment: For informational purposes: `array.reduce(function(sum, n) { return sum + n; }, 0);`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, can you tell me how I should have approached debugging this problem?  I've only been programming for 2 months and sometimes figuring out how to debug is as confusing for me as the algorithm itself.

Comment: @i_made_that sure! You can learn how to it in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), [Firefox](https://getfirebug.com/javascript) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx). But they're almost the same process between all browsers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javascript objects are compared by reference.

`[]` creates a new array instance, which will will never equal your variable.

You want to check the `length`.

Comment: Sigh. yes. I shouldn't have missed that.  Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

```
function arrayIntSum(array) {
    if (array.length === 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else return array.shift() + arrayIntSum(array); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check by this way :
a.length==0

you compared a with [] , being a '[]' [literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals), it has different memory space. and `a` has different memory space. So they are never equal. so recursion cross its **limit**